# When to use "pour" when saying "in order to"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Example:

> J'irai à Londres mercredi prochain avec mes parents acheter les nouveaux livres.

Now, I saw this in a book. I would have thought it would be

> ... avec mes parents *pour* acheter les nouveaux livres.

Why am I mistaken, and/or what is the rule?

Comment: Both are correct. Only grammatical structures differ slightly but the meanings are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both sentences are correct.

- If you use *pour* then “*pour acheter les nouveaux livres*” is a complement which gives a reason. The verb “*aller*” is then understood as “to go”.
- If you don't, “*acheter les nouveaux livres*” is then the direct object of “*irai*”. It's separated from the verb by 3 other complements: one gives the place, a second one gives time and a third one says how. But you can remove all three to understand the sentence: “*J'irai acheter les nouveaux livres*”. Here, the expression “*aller faire quelque chose*“ is used in the future tense.